# Can I update a MySQL table via Email?

Tags: mysql, apache

So I have a small area of my site that I update a lot.  It sure would be nice if I could make it pull from MySQL table and just email that change in.

Anyone done something like this?

I'm using a hosted server running apache.

CLARIFY:
I have a php page that currently gets people's high scores and displays them on the page.  I have been watching the site and every now and then commenting on the scores (by changing the markup of the page).
I just thought that it would be great if I could setup a way to email the comments to my website and have the contents put into my db.

Then on my php side of things, I'll just put whatever is in TABLE-COMMENTS in the comments div.

Comment: Why don't you make it listen to your twitter feed, and just start modifying tables?

Comment: @MorganTocker: Because twitter is limited to 140 characters.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to email your changes to the site and it scrapes the email and inserts the data into the MySQL table? Or are you wanting to have the site generate emails and then when you click a link it updates the DB (via HTTP)? If it is the later, you could do this with HTSQL if you can install third party apps on your hosted service (HTSQL requires Python)? Oh and what server side language are you using?

Comment: OH good... maybe the spammers won't try to sell that email address penis pills and cause your DB to destroy everything as it rushes to place last-second orders for Russian Brides and Nigerian Dictators With Lots of Money.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You would need a server side script that can parse the emails from that address's inbox. Then you could set up a cron job to check the email box every hour or so.

Comment: @Brian Glaz .. this sounds like a real answer for me.  Can you post it as one so I can vote on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You would need a server side script that can parse the emails from that address's inbox. Then you could set up a cron job to check the email box every hour or so.

Of course you should take extra precaution in validating the sender / specific format of these emails, so not just anyone can update your database. (I believe this is what @Marc B was commenting about)